# Pyspark RDD: find index of an element

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I am trying to convert a list in python to rdd and then I need to find elements index using the rdd. For the first part I am doing:

```
list = [[1,2],[1,4]]
rdd = sc.parallelize(list).cache()
```

So now the rdd is actually my list. The thing is that I want to find index of any arbitrary element something like "index" function which works for python lists. I am aware of a function called zipWithIndex which assign index to each element but I could not find proper example in python (there are examples with java and scala).

Thanks.

Comment: By arbitrary element, you mean an arbitrary sublist, like `[1,2]`?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan yes that's what I mean

Comment: For the record, there _is_ [an example of `zipWithIndex` in Pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#zipWithIndex).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `filter` and `zipWithIndex`:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().
filter(lambda (key,index) : key == [1,2]).
map(lambda (key,index) : index).collect()
```

Note that `[1,2]` here can be easily changed to a variable name and this whole expression can be wrapped within a function.

### How It Works

`zipWithIndex` simply returns a tuple of (`item`,`index`) like so:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().collect()
> [([1, 2], 0), ([1, 4], 1)]
```

`filter` finds only those that match a particular criterion (in this case, that `key` equals a specific sublist):

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (key,index) : key == [1,2]).collect()
> [([1, 2], 0)]
```

`map` is fairly obvious, we can just get back the index:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (key,index) : key == [1,2]).
map(lambda (key,index): index).collect()
> [0]
```

and then we can simply get the first element by indexing `[0]` if you want.

Comment: The thing is, when I add "rdd.zipWithIndex.collect()" to my code it returns the following error: "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'collect'"

Comment: You - by which I mean I - forgot a `()`. It should be `rdd.zipWithIndex().collect()`.

Comment: Also note that collect will return a _list_. If you have a truly massive dataset, I beg you not to do `collect` but take a sample first before calling `collect()`.

Comment: @nimafl Updated answer with corrected code. Thanks for catching that :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the list thing and for the answer as well :)

Comment: Is it possible that providing a lambda function to `filter()` is not supported anymore?