# What is the equivalent to Hive's find_in_set function (without registering a temp view)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below dataframe has 2 columns,

- user_id
- user_id_list (array)

requirement is to find the position of user_id in the user_id_list.

Sample record:

```
user_id = x1
user_id_list = ('X2','X1','X3','X6')
```

Result:

```
postition = 2
```

I need the dataframe with 3rd column which has the position of user_id in the list.

Result dataframe columns:

- user_id
- user_id_list
- position

I can achieve this using `find_in_set()` hive function after registering the dataframe as view using `createOrReplaceTempView`.

Is there a sql function available in spark to get this done without registering the view?

Comment: If you only want the index of a specific element from a RDD, you could try the method suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438321/pyspark-rdd-find-index-of-an-element

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to implement an UDF, just as Yura mentioned. Here is a short example of what it can look like:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = List((1, Array(2, 3, 1)), (2, Array(1, 2,3))).toDF("user_id","user_id_list")
df.show

+-------+------------+
|user_id|user_id_list|
+-------+------------+
|      1|   [2, 3, 1]|
|      2|   [1, 2, 3]|
+-------+------------+

val findPosition = udf((user_id: Int, user_id_list: Seq[Int]) => {
  user_id_list.indexOf(user_id)    
})

val df2 = df.withColumn("position", findPosition($"user_id", $"user_id_list"))
df2.show

+-------+------------+--------+
|user_id|user_id_list|position|
+-------+------------+--------+
|      1|   [2, 3, 1]|       2|
|      2|   [1, 2, 3]|       1|
+-------+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such function is Spark SQL API. There's a function to find if array contains a value (called `array_contains`) but that's not what you need.

You could use `posexplode` to explode array to rows with position and then filter by it, like this: `dataframe.select($"id", posexplode($"ids")).filter($"id" === $"col").select($"id", $"pos")`. Still it may be not optimal solution depending on length of a user ids list. Currently (for version 2.1.1) Spark doesn't do optimization to replace above code with direct array lookup - it will generate rows and filter by it.

Also take into the account that this approach will filter out any rows where `user_id` is not in `user_ids_list` so you may want to take extra efforts to overcome this.

I would advice to implement UDF which does exactly what you need. On the downside: Spark can't look into the UDF so it'll have to deserialize data to Java objects and back.

Comment: Could you elaborate on _"that's suboptimal as you may guess."_? We don't know how long `user_id_list` could be and it's natively supported with optimizations. UDFs adds serialization-deserialization layer.

Comment: You are correct, that depends on the length of `user_id_list`. On one side, posexplode will generate a row for each element in the user ids list; on the other side it is natively supported and may be the subject of optimization. Let me update my answer so it will be more accurate, thanks.

Comment: I think the right answer can only be given after we compare the execution plans of each solution and run some performance benchmarks. Care to benchmark your solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a sql function available in spark to get this done without registering the view?

No, but you don't have to register a DataFrame to use `find_in_set` either.

### expr function (with find_in_set)

You can (temporarily) switch to SQL mode using `expr` function instead (see [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object):

> Parses the expression string into the column that it represents

```
val users = Seq(("x1", Array("X2","X1","X3","X6"))).toDF("user_id", "user_id_list")

val positions = users.
  as[(String, Array[String])].
  map { case (uid, ids) => (uid, ids, ids.mkString(",")) }.
  toDF("user_id", "user_id_list", "ids").  // only for nicer column names
  withColumn("position", expr("find_in_set(upper(user_id), ids)")).
  select("user_id", "user_id_list", "position")
scala> positions.show
+-------+----------------+--------+
|user_id|    user_id_list|position|
+-------+----------------+--------+
|     x1|[X2, X1, X3, X6]|       2|
+-------+----------------+--------+
```

### posexplode function

You could also use `posexplode` function (from [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object) that saves you some Scala custom coding and is better optimized than UDFs (that forces deserialization of internal binary rows into JVM objects).

```
scala> users.
  select('*, posexplode($"user_id_list")).
  filter(lower($"user_id") === lower($"col")).
  select($"user_id", $"user_id_list", $"pos" as "position").
  show
+-------+----------------+--------+
|user_id|    user_id_list|position|
+-------+----------------+--------+
|     x1|[X2, X1, X3, X6]|       1|
+-------+----------------+--------+
```