# Splitting and RDD row to different column in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, row, rdd

This is a continuation of my previous question.

I am trying to find the index of 'e' of the following RDD using pyspark:

```
['a,b,c,d,e,f']
```

I am using the method:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().lookup('e')
```

But I get = []

as the Rdd is in the form: 
        [
     ['a,b,c,d,e,f']

I tried

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

so that I use lookup to get the index, but I am still getting []

Please help me. How do I get the Rdd as:

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

So that I can do this method

```
    rdd.zipWithIndex().lookup('e')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438321/pyspark-rdd-find-index-of-an-element

Comment: I tried this method. But inorder to get the index, I need it in the form:  ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] . How do I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue is that you are using whole string as an `array`**

```
['a,b,c,d,e,f']
```

So, here `a,b,c,d,e,f` is all treated as one string. **You need to separate them into separate rows of the RDD you have**. You can simply use `flatMap` to separate the *string* into separate *RDD* *rows* and then use `zipWithIndex()` and `lookUp()`

```
print(rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(",")).zipWithIndex().lookup("e"))
```